# VSCode break comma separated values into rows

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ide, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to separate this format:

```
const { a, b, c, d, e, g, f, g, etc } = alphabet
```

Into

```
const { 
  a, 
  b, 
  c, 
  d, 
  e, 
  g, 
  f, 
  g, 
  etc } = alphabet
```

Easily?

### UPDATE

After endless search for a few days, I decided to spend my weekend creating an extension to achieve this. See my answer below.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Update

I've done this a couple of years ago. Nowadays, I'm using [prettier](https://github.com/prettier/prettier) which has been really helpful and more productive. However, I'm keeping a copy of the plugin I made for ad-hoc purposes and for education.

---

I've been looking for support on this for days but can't find any. So I decided to create an extension called [Break From Comma!](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jzarzoso.break-from-comma)

I hope this helps! [Contributions](https://github.com/janzenz/vscode-break-from-comma) are very much welcome too!

#### Features

- Supports both single and double quotations
- Automatic indentations!

#### Limitation

- It doesn't support multi cursor at the moment.

[image: Demo]

Answer (score 52):

You can use the multi cursor feature in this case.

- Move the list to the position where you would like to see the first element
- Select the first comma
- Execute `editor.action.addSelectionToNextFindMatch` (on Windows it's set to  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> by default, on Mac <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>) until all commas are selected (now you have multiple selections with multiple cursors at every comma).
- Press the right arrow key to set the cursors behind the commas
- Press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
- Adjust the indentation if you want.

**This is what it looks like:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That's how I usually do it but it's too tedious. Nonetheless, I created an extension for this purpose, see my answer below. :)

Comment: This is great, another powerful tool with Ctrl+d. Thanks!

Comment: For anyone using VS 2019, after you select your text, the default keyboard shortcut is `ALT` + `SHIFT` + `.` to find the next item like what you have selected.

Comment: Serio? my line is 300 commas... Anything better?